# Неверно распознается кодировка строки из файла application.properties

Tags: android, spring, кодировка, spring-boot, кириллица

Я в файле `application.properties` задал строку пути до файла на диске. Путь содержит кириллические символы (это изменить нельзя). Соответственно spring boot\java видит их как:

```
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А какая сейчас кодировка у файла application.properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Конфигурационный файл *.property* имеет кодировку *ISO-8859-1*

 -> не поддерживает кириллицу в явном виде, но вы можете переконвертировать кириллицу при помощи native2ascii. В этом случае у вас получится совершенно не читаемый текст, но java прочитает все нормально =)

Другой вариант использовать формат *.yml* для описания настроек приложения. В отличие от *.properies* он имеет кодировку  *UTF-8* так что проблем с кириллицей у вас не возникнет.

SpringBoot отлично ладит с *.yml* конфигурационными файлами, так что проблем не должно возникнуть.